# How can I programmatically ensure that gradle components aren't removed without updating settings.gradle?

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

So what happens is that someone removes a component and then `sonarqube` drops dead because `settings.gradle` wasn't updated to show the component as removed. Since my team are all Gradle newbs, this makes things pretty brittle. I want to fail immediately with a message in this case. My thinking is to iterate over every project's root directory and make sure that there's a `build.gradle` file still there but there may be better ways and I don't know the API that well myself yet, to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can imagine is to use an own build step checking the *settings.gradle* file.

Depending on the scm system you can parse the changed files and search for removed components, but this will be get overhead.
Perhaps you are better to include an user information or prompt til they are doing it automatically.